# HTTP Request inside laravel command not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a laravel command to call Mercado Libre API. When I run this sample script in my htdocs from XAMPP folder, it returns the body data, but when I run from my laravel command it returns the body empty.

This is the script:

```
$app_id = 'xxx';
$secret_key = 'xxxx';
$meli = new Meli($app_id, $secret_key);
$access_token = 'xxxx';
$params = array('access_token' => $access_token);
$result = $meli->get('/users/me', $params, true);
```

This is the command

```
public function handle()
    {        

    $app_id = 'xxx';
    $secret_key = 'xxx';
    $meli = new Meli($app_id, $secret_key);
    $access_token = 'xxx';
    $params = array('access_token' => $access_token);
    $result = $meli->get('/users/me', $params, true);            
    }
```

EDIT

The scirpts are running in the same environment. I test and curl is callable.

```
if(is_callable('curl_init')){
          //Code here
            print_r("normal");
        }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have curl enabled in the environment where are running Laravel? it wasn't clear if you ran your working test and Laravel in the same environment. The Mercado Libre Library depends on Curl. You could try with something like `function_exists('curl_exec')`

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert thanks for the help. Yes, curl_exec exists and is callabled (I updated my question with this). Both scripts are running in my local machine/same environment.

Comment: What triggers that job? Is it run on a queue?